# Url rewrite by global.asax and Error 404 in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am working on a project with following properties :

```
Asp.net
C# 
.Net Framework 4
IIS 7
```

and in it , I use the `Application_BeginRequest` to rewrite manually like this :

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sendet, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool IsUploading = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsUloading"] == "1";

        if (Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            return;
        }

        string Path = Request.RawUrl;
        string QueryString = "";

        if (Request.QueryString.Count != 0)
        {
            string[] u = Path.Split(new char[] { '?' });
            Path = u[0];
            QueryString = u[1];
        }

        string url = "";

        if (Path.EndsWith(".css") || Path.EndsWith(".js") || Path.EndsWith(".png") || Path.EndsWith(".jpg") || Path.EndsWith(".jpeg") || Path.EndsWith(".bmp") || Path.EndsWith(".htm") || Path.EndsWith(".png") || Path.EndsWith(".gif") || Path.EndsWith(".fla") || Path.EndsWith(".swf") || Path.EndsWith(".axd") || Path.EndsWith(".xml") || Path.EndsWith(".ashx"))
            return;

        if (!Path.EndsWith("/"))
            Path += "/";

        IEnumerator<string> Part = Path.Split(new char[] { '/' }).AsEnumerable<string>().GetEnumerator();

        if (Part.MoveNext() && Part.MoveNext())
        {

            if (Part.Current == "")
                url = "Default.aspx";

            else if (Part.Current.ToLower() == "public")
            {

                if (Part.MoveNext() && Part.Current.ToLower() == "install")
                    url = "Public/Install.aspx";
                else
                    url = "Public/PageNotFound.aspx";

            }

            else
                url = "Public/PageNotFound.aspx";

        }
        else
            url = "Public/PageNotFound.aspx";

        if (url.Contains("?"))
            Context.RewritePath("~/" + url + "&" + QueryString);
        else
            Context.RewritePath("~/" + url + "?" + QueryString);

    }
```

now when try to browse the page `localhost:97` , browser start to open the Default.aspx but if I try to open `localhost:97/Public/Install` the browser give me this error :

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Where is the error ?!!!

**UPDATE1** : When I try to brows `localhost:97/Public/Install`, VS does not stopped on the breakpoints that I put in this event. I think my request was rejected in IIS.

**UPDATE2** : I know that my code is one hundred percent correct, because we are working on TFS server and the other computer does not have any problem with that and just my computer encountered with this problem.

Sorry about my bad English. I am new. For more detail comment me.

Comment: Start by dropping in some logging/debugging statements so you can see what the code is doing with your path.  Since you are manually processing a path and also possibly doing a rewrite, it gets very confusing what the final request is going to be.

Comment: @mellamokb , I tried it and set some breakpoints , but my request stopped in IIS , an VS does not act on breakpoints, what do you mean exactly ?!

Answer (score 0):

i think it could be great using aspnet routing to achive your goal.

you can create your own path e.g "public/install" which is one route.

If it is match aspnet move there also you can use a catch all route which is use to show a 404 403 500 and so on.more simple and reduce your code drammatically.

it is a simple example in vbnet:

```
  Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls()
    'blocca il trattamento dei vari snippet
    routes.Add(New Route("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}", New StopRoutingHandler()))
    routes.Add(New Route("route", New StopRoutingHandler()))
    routes.Add(New Route("bundles/css", New StopRoutingHandler()))
    'routes.Add(New Route("script/zx", New StopRoutingHandler()))
    'routes.Add(New Route("script/av", New StopRoutingHandler()))
    'routes.Add(New Route("script/pf", New StopRoutingHandler()))
    'routes.Add(New Route("script/bv", New StopRoutingHandler()))
    'sezione errori
    routes.MapPageRoute("404", "NotFound", "~/error/404.aspx", False)
    routes.MapPageRoute("500", "ServerError", "~/error/500.aspx", False)
    routes.MapPageRoute("503", "ServerUnavailable", "~/error/503.aspx", False)
    'fonti base
    routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "", "~/Default.aspx", False)
    routes.MapPageRoute("DefaultVasVoip", "vas-e-voip", "~/route/vas-voip/DefaultVasVoip.aspx", False, New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.name = "default"}))
    routes.MapPageRoute("VasVoipRoute", "vas-e-voip/{service}/{id}", "~/route/vas-voip/DefaultVasVoip.aspx", False, New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.name = "VasVoipRoute"}))
    routes.MapPageRoute("MarketingRoute", "marketing/{service}/{id}", "~/route/marketing/DefaultMarketing.aspx", False, New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.name = "MarketingRoute"}))
    routes.MapPageRoute("DefaultMarketing", "marketing", "~/route/marketing/DefaultMarketing.aspx", False, New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.name = "default"}))
    routes.MapPageRoute("HostingRoute", "hosting/{service}/{id}", "~/route/hosting/DefaultHosting.aspx", False, New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.name = "HostingRoute"}))
    routes.MapPageRoute("Optimization", "seo/{service}/{id}", "~/route/seo/DefaultSeo.aspx", False, New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.name = "Optimization"}))
    routes.MapPageRoute("DefaultSeoHosting", "hosting-e-seo", "~/route/hosting/DefaultHosting.aspx", False, New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.name = "default"}))
    routes.MapPageRoute("Contact", "contatti", "~/route/Contact.aspx", False)
    routes.MapPageRoute("Login", "login", "~/route/ssl/login.aspx", False, New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.name = "login", .ssl = True}))
    routes.MapPageRoute("LoginRedirect", "login/redirect", "~/route/ssl/login.aspx", False, New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.name = "redirect"}))
    routes.MapPageRoute("Admin", "ssl/admin/", "~/route/ssl/private/admin/Default.aspx")
    routes.MapPageRoute("Customer", "ssl/customer/", "~/route/ssl/private/customer/Default.aspx")
    routes.MapPageRoute("About", "chi-siamo", "~/route/About.aspx", False)
    routes.MapPageRoute("articles", "articles", "~/route/article/Default.aspx", False)
    routes.MapPageRoute("article", "article/{gg}/{mm}/{yyyy}/{id}/{title}", "~/route/article/Default.aspx", False)
    routes.MapPageRoute("termini", "termini-e-condizioni", "~/route/Termini.aspx", False)
    routes.MapPageRoute("privacy", "privacy", "~/route/Privacy.aspx", False)
    routes.MapPageRoute("portfolio", "portfolio", "~/route/portfolio.aspx", False)
    routes.MapPageRoute("faq", "faq", "~/route/faq.aspx", False)
    'Catch All per ogni richiesta errata 
    routes.MapPageRoute("CatchAllErrors", "{*url}", "~/InvalidRequest.aspx", False)
End Sub
```

I hope it could help you.